# Dockerfile: Permission denied when trying to install ruby-build

Tags: ruby, docker, centos, dockerfile

I'm trying to install ruby-build as a non-root in my Dockerfile but I am getting a permission denied error. How can I give the deploy user access to do so?

#### error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/ruby-build': Permission denied
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.6

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install git openssl-devel openssh-server sudo openssl readline-devel readline zlib-devel zlib libxml2-devel libxml2 libxslt-devel libxslt nginx tar gcc libaio libaio-devel -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-12.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN sed -i -e "s/Defaults    requiretty.*/ #Defaults    requiretty/g" /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

# RUN adduser deploy -g wheel -p Password1
RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -G wheel deploy && sed -ri 's/^(%wheel.*)(ALL)$/\1NOPASSWD: \2/' /etc/sudoers
USER deploy

RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git $HOME/.rbenv/
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git $HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN $HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh

ENV PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
RUN source $HOME/.bash_profile
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc

RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
RUN rbenv global 2.2.3
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update --system'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install bundler rails-api --no-rdoc --no-ri'

RUN touch /etc/sysconfig/network

EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3389
```

Comment: What's the question here? Non-root users can't generally write to `/usr/local` paths.

Comment: I wan't to know how to give the user permission to do so.

Comment: You change the permissions on the directory as root. But that's unlikely to be the actual answer here. More likely you should either install it as root or install it to some non-system location as your non-root user.

Comment: I've tried that using `RUN chown -R deploy /usr/local/share/` but I would lead to more permission denied until chown would not work. Now however I get `install: cannot create regular file /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install': File exists`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do install ruby-build as root using the deploy user. "Installing as a standalone program (advanced)" as per [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build).

You can try something like this (using sudo):

```
FROM centos:6.6

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install git openssl-devel openssh-server sudo openssl readline-devel readline zlib-devel zlib libxml2-devel libxml2 libxslt-devel libxslt nginx tar gcc libaio libaio-devel -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-12.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN sed -i -e "s/Defaults    requiretty.*/ #Defaults    requiretty/g" /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

# RUN adduser deploy -g wheel -p Password1
RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -G wheel deploy && echo '%wheel  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/wheel
USER deploy

RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git $HOME/.rbenv/
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git $HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN sudo $HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh

ENV PATH /home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
RUN source $HOME/.bash_profile
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc

RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
RUN rbenv global 2.2.3
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update --system'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install bundler rails-api --no-rdoc --no-ri'

RUN touch /etc/sysconfig/network

EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3389
```

Comment: That fixed that but now it can't find rbenv `/home/deploy/.bashrc: line 9: rbenv: command not found
/home/deploy/.bash_profile: line 13: rbenv: command not found
 ---> 4394fb4d41af
Removing intermediate container f6e5a3cb4952
Step 17 : ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc
 ---> Running in 3b8ec935df66
 ---> 213058afb6bc
Removing intermediate container 3b8ec935df66
Step 18 : RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
 ---> Running in 5ec85d5beae7
/bin/sh: rbenv: command not found`

Comment: yeah or to `ENV PATH /home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH`